# JSONpath fields with same name

Tags: json, twitter

I'm trying to get the user id's from twitter response (asking for several users)

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup

But if i try

$.[*].id  OR  $..id

all fields with id (even nested fields) are retrieved.

How can i get the "id" field placed at first level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would only get the first-level id's with the following query `$[*].id`. I believe this is what you were asking for; let me know if I misunderstood you.